# Div flutuante não está funcionando direito

Tags: jquery, html, css, div

[image: Ilustração do que estou criando]

Preciso criar uma div flutuante no canto esquerdo do site. No entanto, ela está no meio do site e só vai acompanhar a rolagem de um certo ponto até outro. Como na imagem ilustrando, a div flutuante tem que ir do inicio do conteúdo até o final dele, parando antes da "barra".

Eu testei alguns códigos que achei pela internet mas nenhum funcionou direito, então eu meio que tentei fazer uns ajustes próprios.

Estou utilizando este código jQuery:

```
 var cartaz = SC(".cartaz-flutuante");
        SC(window).scroll(function(){            
            var topo_cartaz = cartaz.offset().top;
            var y_fixo = 40;
            if (topo_cartaz < 40) {
                cartaz.animate({
                    top: y_fixo+SC(document).scrollTop()+"px"
                    },{duration:500,queue:false}
                );
            }
        });
```

A altura de '40" é apenas uma margem para dar a div, para não ficar totalmente encostada.
E aquele "if" eu tentei fazer para quando a altura da pagina ficar menor que a margem, o efeito de deslize da div começa a funcionar... Só que não está funcionando... E se eu tirar o if, até funciona, mas dai fica doidão e a div flutuante some se eu der um scroll total do site.

Comment: Se você alinhar o box conteúdo a direita e colocar a div flutuante como position: fixed, não resolve?

Comment: A estrutura do html\css é bem básica, como no desenho. A div que deve ser flutuante está "float left" e o conteúdo "float right". A div já está em absolute, o que posso fazer é deixar como "fixed", dai sim ela acompanha o scroll.. o problema é que não tem efeito, e preciso controlar o limite de movimento, já que ela fica fixa no site como um todo, indo do header até o footer, e não somente aonde quero.

Comment: poderia colocar um exemplo no JsFiddle?

Comment: Peguei a sugestão do @FredDutra e tentei criar código próprio. Pode ser visualizado aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/rmugb3j0/ mas não funcionou! HAHA Não sei por que. Mesmo assim dá para ter uma noção de como está meu código. A div flutuante desliza com a página e para no final da div do conteúdo, como programado. O problema é que quando dou scroll pra cima, a div não volta a acompanhar.. Como faço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe alguns plugins JQUERY que pode servir para sua necessidade:

http://someweblog.com/demo/hcsticky/

http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html

Comment: Poisé, mas o meu site já está com bastante plugin e não queria adicionar mais um. Pelo visto vou ter que usar mesmo, rsrs. Obrigado, vou dar uma olhada nesses links.

Comment: Peguei a sugestão do @FredDutra e tentei criar código próprio. Pode ser visualizado aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/rmugb3j0/ mas não funcionou! HAHA Não sei por que. Mesmo assim dá para ter uma noção de como está meu código. A div flutuante desliza com a página e para no final da div do conteúdo, como programado. O problema é que quando dou scroll pra cima, a div não volta a acompanhar.. Como faço?

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que haja uma possibilidade de fazer isso sem a adição de Plugins.

### HTML

```
<div class="conteudo">Conteúdo da div</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteúdo da div</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteúdo da div</div>
<div id="fixa_temporaria">Esta div é estática</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteúdo da div</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteúdo da div</div>
<div class="conteudo">Conteúdo da div</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0}
.conteudo{width: 100%; height: 300px; margin-bottom: 12px;}
#fixa_temporaria{width: 300px;  background: black; color: white; padding: 6px; position: relative; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;}
```

### JS

```
var sticky_offset;
$(document).ready(function() {

    var original_position_offset = $('#sticky_for_a_while').offset();
    sticky_offset = original_position_offset.top;
    $('#fixa_temporaria').css('position', 'fixed');


});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var sticky_height = $('#fixa_temporaria').outerHeight();
    var where_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var window_height = $(window).height();


    if((where_scroll + window_height) > sticky_offset) {
        $('#fixa_temporaria').css('position', 'relative');
    }

    if((where_scroll + window_height) < (sticky_offset + sticky_height))  {
        $('#fixa_temporaria').css('position', 'fixed');
    }

});
```

Veja se isso funciona.. não testei ainda.

Dica: evite usar plugins, eles pesam, dão problemas com frequência e você não tem controle total sobre eles.

Comment: Exatamente. O site já tem bastante plugin e não queria usar mais um para algo simples. Ainda não testei, mas assim que der tempo, eu testo e comento novamente. Obrigado :D

Comment: Peguei a sugestão do @FredDutra e tentei criar código próprio. Pode ser visualizado aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/rmugb3j0/ mas não funcionou! HAHA Não sei por que. Mesmo assim dá para ter uma noção de como está meu código. A div flutuante desliza com a página e para no final da div do conteúdo, como programado. O problema é que quando dou scroll pra cima, a div não volta a acompanhar.. Como faço?

Answer (score 2):

O que você está fazendo de errado é utilizar a propriedade `position:absolute`, utilizando o position setado como `absolute` o `float` não funciona.

Comment: Bah, agora não consigo mais testar usando meu modelo antigo. Acabei utilizando um plugin mesmo. Valeu.